# to increase MaxPermSize memory in Java by command line

Tags: java, java-6

Could you please explain me how to increase this PermSpace size. I am using Gate application and loading huge amount of data and large number of plugins and unfortunately after every run it gives the error about the out of memory maxPermSpace.

I searched everywhere, but I could not find how to increase this size through command line or may be the file where I could update the data?

I really need some help in order to complete my project. Please explain how to do this by command line I am using jdk1.6.0_38 version and win7(64bit).

Comment: This question is obsolete with Java8 because the previous PermSpace is now unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `-XX:MaxPermSize`. A sample command could be:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Maybe combined with 32 bit addresses for objects, instead of 64 bits

```
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Enables the use of compressed pointers (object references represented as 32 bit offsets instead of 64-bit pointers) for optimized 64-bit performance with Java heap sizes less than 32gb.

See [VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

Also check that String internalization does not occur. XML introduced in the past a `String.intern()` to save space, but then Perm space grows. So maybe check your XML settings.

Answer (score 0):

From Gate's documentation

2.7.5 I got the error: Could not reserve enough space for object heap [#]

> GATE doesn’t use the JAVA_OPTS variable. The default memory allocations are defined in the gate/build.xml file but you can override them by creating a file called build.properties in the same directory containing
>   `runtime.start.memory=256m`
>   `runtime.max.memory=1048m`

Check your gate/build.xml file and include the options cited in the other answers