# Java memory allocation difference between DXX and XX

Tags: java, memory, mule

I'm automating a mule stack. The client wants his java binary to run with

```
-DXX:MaxPermSize=4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
```

Can someone explain the difference between `DXX` and `XX` memory allocation?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587727/to-increase-maxpermsize-memory-in-java-by-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-D[...]` is just a flag to set a "system property". Unless anything *looks* at that system property, it will have no effect at all.

For example:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("XX:MaxPermSize"));
```

... will print out "4096M" in your example, but would normally print out `null` as the property wouldn't be defined.

The second flag is a flag the JVM itself can use to affect memory allocation - although any `-X` flag is non-standard and subject to change without notice.

Basically, it sounds like your client may be a bit confused, and you should ask them if they have any good, solid *reason* for specifying a system property as well as a JVM flag.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

-D is to add system property.

like

```
-Denv=test/live
```

so env will be test or live.